# Filtering values based on the date ranges

Tags: sql-server, date

Request your help in acheiving the following result  from the date set below

I have the below result set

```
CampaignName    Matchfrom   MatchTo 
a               08-09-2013  07-11-2013  
a               10-09-2013  10-11-2013  
a               08-11-2013  07-01-2014  
a               09-11-2013  08-01-2014
```

above set is sorted on matchfrom date column. First row will be considered as a master

now the query should filter out the rows in which matchfrom lies in the date range of the master.

This, I achieved using a self join. But now the third row is completely out of range of the master(1st row). This should now be considered as the master and it should filter out the 4th row.

Final result set will be  like the below, marked as pass and fail

```
CampaignName    Matchfrom   MatchTo 
a               08-09-2013  07-11-2013  PASS
a               10-09-2013  10-11-2013  FAIL
a               08-11-2013  07-01-2014  PASS
a               09-11-2013  08-01-2014  FAIL
```

Can someone advise me on this

Comment: Please improve your question by specifying the language (SQL it seems), as well as properly formatting your resultsets using the __code block__ button in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

With you data you'll have to do a bit more scrubbing but the code below should get you in the right direction.  You have to be careful because your MatchFrom and MatchTo in your "Master Record"go opposite directions than all of your other data.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpCampaign(
CampaignName varchar(1),
Matchfrom Date,
MatchTo  Date
)

INSERT INTO #tmpCampaign VALUES 
('a','08-09-2013','07-11-2013'),
('a','10-09-2013','10-11-2013'),  
('a','08-11-2015','07-01-2014'),
('a','09-11-2013','08-01-2014') 

;WITH Campaign AS(
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY campaignName ORDER BY MatchFrom) as CampRank
FROM #tmpCampaign)

SELECT c1.*, c2.MatchFrom as MasterFrom, c2.MatchTo as MasterTo,
CASE WHEN c1.Matchfrom >= c2.MatchFrom AND c1.Matchfrom <= c2.MatchTo THEN 'Pass'
ELSE 'Fail' END as PassFail
FROM Campaign as c1
JOIN Campaign as c2
ON c1.CampaignName = c2.CampaignName and c2.CampRank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this is create problem when date duplication happens but as for your result set i have picked the datekey and done the partition according to that to achieve results

```
;With Cte as
(select Campaignname,
        matchfrom,
        matchto,
ROW_number()OVER(PARTITION BY right(matchfrom, len(matchfrom) - charindex('-', matchfrom) - 3)ORDER BY Campaignname)RN  
from #tmpCampaign )
select Campaignname,
        matchfrom,
        matchto,
        Case when RN = 1 then 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END
 from Cte
```